# Add OR condition in left join using Django ORM

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-admin, django-orm

How do I add an OR condition on the first LEFT OUTER JOIN ? something like this:

`LEFT OUTER JOIN "orders_orderedproductsku" ON ("manual_shipments"."id" = "orders_orderedproductsku"."shipment_id" OR "manual_shipments"."id" = "orders_orderedproductsku"."return_shipment_id")`

Already tried other workaround but still no hope. Is there a possible that I could add the OR condition properly?

Here's my query set:

````
shipment_rebooking = queryset \
            .filter(status='BOOKING_CANCELED') \
            .annotate(orderedproductsku__shipment_id=F('orderedproductsku__shipment_id'),
                      logistics_shipment__shipment_id=F('logisticsshipments__shipment_id'),
                      orderedproductsku__status=F('orderedproductsku__status'),
                      logistics_shipment__status=F('logisticsshipments__status'),
                      logistics_shipment__id=F('logisticsshipments__id')) \
            .filter(Q(logistics_shipment__status='BOOKING_CANCELED') | Q(logistics_shipment__id__isnull=True),
                    orderedproductsku__status__in=['PREPARING_FOR_SHIPMENT', 'SCHEDULED_FOR_RETURN', 'SCHEDULED_FOR_RETURN_NO_REFUND']) \
            .order_by('-created_at') \
            .distinct()```

the raw query is like this:
```SELECT DISTINCT "manual_shipments"."created_at",
    "manual_shipments"."updated_at",
    "manual_shipments"."deleted_at",
    "manual_shipments"."id",
    "manual_shipments"."order_reference_number",
    "manual_shipments"."logistics_provider_id",
    "manual_shipments"."logistics_provider_shipment_id",
    "manual_shipments"."logistics_name",
    "manual_shipments"."tracking_number",
    "manual_shipments"."tracking_url",
    "manual_shipments"."shipping_cost",
    "manual_shipments"."status",
    "manual_shipments"."shipment_type",
    "manual_shipments"."seller_id",
    "manual_shipments"."buyer_id",
    "manual_shipments"."latest_logistics_shipment_id",
    "manual_shipments"."latest_status_id",
    "orders_orderedproductsku"."shipment_id" AS "orderedproductsku__shipment_id",
    "logistics_shipments"."shipment_id" AS "logistics_shipment__shipment_id",
    "orders_orderedproductsku"."status" AS "orderedproductsku__status",
    "logistics_shipments"."status" AS "logistics_shipment__status",
    "logistics_shipments"."id" AS "logistics_shipment__id"
FROM "manual_shipments"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "orders_orderedproductsku" ON ("manual_shipments"."id" = "orders_orderedproductsku"."shipment_id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "logistics_shipments" ON ("manual_shipments"."id" = "logistics_shipments"."shipment_id")
WHERE ("manual_shipments"."status" = BOOKING_CANCELED
                            AND ("logistics_shipments"."status" = BOOKING_CANCELED
                                                OR "logistics_shipments"."id" IS NULL)
                            AND "orders_orderedproductsku"."status" IN (PREPARING_FOR_SHIPMENT, SCHEDULED_FOR_RETURN, SCHEDULED_FOR_RETURN_NO_REFUND))
ORDER BY "manual_shipments"."created_at" DESC```
````

Comment: Can you show us the code before "queryset"? As in, what that's made of "Model.objects.filter()... "

Comment: This is before the queryset: def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super(ScheduledReturnOrderedProductSkuAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)

Answer (score 0):

first of all left join,right join leave these kind of things. Django ORM is there so that you can use functions to do database operations. Django has wide variety of functions to use .

To do OR in the django filter query do like this :-

```
from django.db.models import Q
users = User.objects.filter(Q(email='sarath@gmail.com') | Q(first_name='john'))
```

This query means - give users whose email is 'sarath@gmail.com' or first name is 'john'  .

The  '|' stands for OR.

using Q you can combine any number of filters.